# Regular expression for SWIFT processing

Tags: regex

Input

This is not a proposal. 1. This is the first proposal. This is the extension of first proposal. This is further extension. 2. This is second proposal. 3. This is the 3rd proposal. And the extension. 4. This is the fourth proposal. This is not a proposal.

Expected output 4 matches

1. This is the first proposal. This is the extension of first proposal. This is further extension. **(match 1)**
2. This is second proposal. **(match 2)**
3. This is the 3rd proposal. And the extension. **(match 3)**
4. This is the fourth proposal. **(match 4)**

Pl suggest a RegEx.

Comment: You can try yourself. Use `\d` to match a digit. To match 0 or more, use `*` after it. Match a dot with `\.`. Use lazy dot matching `.*?` to grab everything before some boundary. 
The boundary can be set with a look-ahead (`(?=)`). Use alterantions with `|`. Use end-of-string `$`, and a whitespace shorthand character class `\s`.

Comment: Thanks much, I am very new to REGEX; It will be of great help if you can share how the REGEX you suggested may look like

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d+\..*?(?=(\d+\.)|$)/g
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ7tJ8/1)

```
\d+\..*?
```

it's no-greedy,when it matched follow lookahead regex,it will stopped match this time,and then match another one,in your example,it matched 4 times.

```
(?=(\d+\.)|$)
```

Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched.

Comment: \d\..*?(?=(\d\.))|$ Thanks Kerwin it worked except it didn't pick the match 4

Comment: `\d\..*?(?=(\d\.))|$`  should change to `\d\..*?(?=(\d\.)|$)`    Move the `$` in to lookahead part.